# "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of null"

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a problem with my PHP and JavaScript code.

I put my simplified code here. So first step, I want to select the trip "Walking" then submit. I got my trip number 50 and it shows a check-box. After that, I want to select the check-box and click the "select checkbox" button. Then it should call `myFunction()`.

But the code inside `myFunction()` is not getting the result because I got the error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of null

And I tried to put `myFunction()` inside `<head></head>`, but it did not work as well.
Any suggestion guys?

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form action = "thispage.php" method = "post">
<select name="typesSelect">
    <option value="">Walking</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="searchFormSubmit" value="Search" />
</form>

<button onclick="myFunction();">Select Checkbox</button>

<?php
$trip = 1;
if(isset($_POST['searchFormSubmit'])) 
{
$trip = 50;
?>
<input type='checkbox' id="myTrip<?php echo $trip;?>">  

<?php}

?>


<script>
function myFunction()
{

trips = <?php echo JSON_encode($trip); ?>;
var array;
initialize();
for(var i=0;i<trips.length;i++){
             if(document.getElementById("myTrip"+trips[i]+"").checked){                             
                $.get('/ajax.php?function=geoData&trip_id='+trips[i], function(data){data=JSON.parse(data);array=data;addLine(data)})
        }

}   
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Declare trips before assign. Or `var trips = <?php echo JSON_encode($trip); ?>;`

Comment: in your javascript you are iterating from #myTrip0 through #myTrip50, but in the php you are only creating a single checkbox.  Perhaps you just cut out too much code in your example, but you are hard coding the input to always be #myTrip50 so the javascript loop is going to throw an exception since the ID doesnt exist and you are trying to find an attribute of an undefined element

Answer (score 0):

As @lonewolf217 mentioned in the comment you are looking for an element that doesn't exist.

You should do something similar to this:

```
for(var i=0;i<trips.length;i++){
             var elem = document.getElementById("myTrip"+trips[i]+"");
             if(elem && elem.checked){                             
                $.get('/ajax.php?function=geoData&trip_id='+trips[i], function(data){data=JSON.parse(data);array=data;addLine(data)})
        }

}
```

Whenever using getElementById always check that the element returned exists before looking for a property.